WPF C# Windows Tray app with Custom url handler(Open app from url)
I am creating a WPF C# tray app which can be opened from url like (Application1://) from browser,
The app is opening from url before I change it to a Tray app.
`

I am able to launch the app from url Application1:// from browser n numeber of times
It is opening only single window even on multiple times I hit the url `
**
After I introduce code to make that as a Tray app and My app is not running anymore**

1. I am not able to open the app from url Application1:// from browser n numeber of times 2. Also multiple instances of app is getting added to the Tray
I tried multiple approach could not able to crack it, this is the url https://github.com/mani-fullstackio/wpf-trayapp-customurl-handler of my code. Kindly help me to resolve this issue

I tried removing the code added to have as tray app it is working fine, but If I have that as tray app it is not working

